# Convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and open sets that contain them.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

I have a question that is bothering me, and would appreciate any help.

I have a compact convex set $A$ in $R^2$, and an open set $U$ such that $A \subset U$.

Is there an open convex set (or a star domain is enough) $B$ such that $A \subset B \subset U$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing of this topic, I am just writing this to place a bet! I bet there is :P

Comment: Maybe you can enlarge $A$ by some very small homothetic transformation of ratio $1+\delta$ such that it is still contained within $U$ (which should be possible because $U$ is open), and that $A$ is strictly contained within this enlarged version. Then you can take $B$ to be the enlarged version minus the boundary, which is an open set.

Comment: If a counterexample exists, I guess the best strategy to find one would be to use the closed lower half-plane as closed convex set, and the set below the graph of some sufficiently weird, but still suitable positive function as the open set.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add "compact" instead of closed. Bass I think that this is a good strategy, I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Since $A$ is compact, there is a $\delta > 0$ with $\lVert x-y\rVert \geqslant \delta$ for all $x\in A$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus U$. Then the Minkowski sum of $A$ and the open $\delta$ ball around $0$, $$A + B_{\delta}(0) = \{ x + z : x \in A,\,\lVert z \rVert < \delta\} = B_{\delta}(A) = \{ z \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \operatorname{dist}(z,A) < \delta\}$$ is an open convex set between $A$ and $U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Great thanks, just why is there such a $\delta$?

Comment: Because $A$ is compact. $f \colon z \mapsto \operatorname{dist}(z,\mathbb{R}^2\setminus U)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $U = f^{-1}\bigl((0,+\infty)\bigr)$, so $f$ is strictly positive on $A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!!